# Restcomm Android SDK and libjingle

Tags: java, android, sdk, restcomm

I am wondering how to get libjingle when checking out the SDK from git.
What I ended up doing was to add libjingle as compile dependency in build.gradle:

```
compile 'io.pristine:libjingle:11139@aar'
```

but looks like the interface is changed from what you use in the SDK, so not sure about what libjingle version to use.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so what we do to avoid the repo getting huge because of carrying binaries, we only place the binaries in the releases. So I'd suggest downloading latest .tar.bz2 from [here](https://github.com/RestComm/restcomm-android-sdk/releases/tag/v1.0.0-BETA4) and copying over native and non-native libs from restcomm.android.sdk/libs/libjingle_peerconnection*.jar and restcomm.android.sdk/libs/jniLibs/armeabi-v7a/libjingle_peerconnection*.so to the same locations in the source tree. That way they should be discoverable in the Android Studio project.

These are going to be turned into maven dependencies at some point to avoid such issues.

Now about io.pristine:libjingle:11139@aar that you used, it's going to be a problem as this build is much earlier than what we have in restcomm-android-sdk and indeed the API is different in some respects.

Comment: Thanks, 11139 was the latest I was able to find, but I'll do as you said.

Comment: Yeah, I share your pain, until Google publishes ready-made libraries for mobile I'm afraid its going to be hard. For iOS I believe they are working on a CocoaPod, but for Android I'm no sure :(

Comment: Thanks, where do I need to copy the jars from dependencies/libs? My studio does not seem to find them.

Comment: @mehturt, I think dependencies/libs is obsolete. As described above you should have your .jars at restcomm.android.sdk/libs/ (i.e. libjingle_peerconnection*.jar and log4j*.jar) and your .so at restcomm.android.sdk/libs/jniLibs/armeabi-v7a/ (i.e. libjingle_peerconnection*.so). Remember that we are using a scheme where for the webrtc lib, there is an unversioned symlink pointing to the actual versioned file.